# Hotwire laptop to skip power checks

Tags: boot, laptop, memory, motherboard

I have a System76 Clevo rebrand W25AEU laptop.  The motherboard is model 6-71-W24E0-D03.  It started getting difficult to turn the machine one and I assumed it was do to the cheap method used. One day it was working, turned it off, and immediately tried to restart. Everything lights up and things start spinning, but in less than a half second it turns back off.

So, after a lot of messing around I found that with the ram removed the computer will turn on and stay on for a minute, maybe more.  Oh, important: I never tried this why connected to a monitor to see if it has errors or such things.  RAM in and it turns off.  I also found a high temp 105 C, 330 uF, 25V capacitor that looked like it leaked (electrolytic).  It is component PU223 and part of the Vcore 1 system.  This system is right after the RAM power supply check during boot up.

Any thoughts guys? Could the video cause this behavior?  FYI, intel integrated graphics.  Do you think everything in the boot sequence is good up to that point? Or if that is very likely?  Oh, I bought a new motherboard and used all the old components except the MOBO and it is going solid for about a year now.

I can supply schematics for the motherboard as well as the boot sequences.

Thanks guys.

Comment: Sounds like the leaky cap caused this behaviour. But is there an actual problem? Or are you just asking about something you already fixed a year ago?

Comment: Yeah, the board is still dead and recently I have gone back to to it.  I have an i3 that I got for free that is the same socket so that is why I am back at it. At the connection points on the capacitor there was (I've remove capacitor) thick brownish stuff that looked like a semi-dry liquid.

Answer (score 0):

If the cap is bad, it most likely will have blown out the vent at the top, and will be slightly bulged, can you verify that this is the case?

If the capacitor did indeed burst, you may have damaged some hardware, on a motherboard, a capacitor of that size seems as if it would be related to the power supply, conditioning the power from the power supply for some mother board chip.

Comment: There is no noticeable deformation of the capacitor, but as I said above, there is a brownish liquid at the connection points.  The schematics, to the best of my ability to read them, have the capacitor in the v-core portion and no where else.  I don't know if the capacitor is the problem though.  There are zero signs of damage anywhere else on the board, but internal damage is possible.